# Order column inside PIVOT on the basis of max(count_date) for each value inside in condition

Tags: oracle

I have users name in column users, I want to display all users as a column and the order of representation of column must be in descending order of their sum of data.

query:

```
select * 
from (
  select sum(tran_count) over (partition by schema) as table_name 
  from main_table
) pivot (sum(tran_count) for users in ('abc','lmn','pqr'));
```

ans:

```
schema   table   abc   lmn  pqr
pm       sector   32  216  12
history  trn     321   61   4
tap      issuer   43  325   2
count:           396 602 18
```

so I want to represent the column abc,lmn and pqr in order of count of their data:

required answer:

```
schema   table   lmn   abc  pqr
pm       sector   216   32  12
history  trn       61  321   4
tap      issuer   325   43   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use (sub)query in pivot's `in` clause. What you can do is to rank users according to their summaric values and use these three values (1, 2, 3) in `in`. Then either use my inner query, which presents user names and sums in separate columns or make a final union, where names are listed in first row and sums in rows below as strings.

```
with t as (
    select * 
      from (
        select dense_rank() over (order by smu desc, users) rn, 
               schema_, table_, users, smt
          from (
            select schema_, table_, users, sum(tran_count) smt, 
                   sum(sum(tran_count)) over (partition by users) smu
              from main_table
              group by schema_, table_, users))
      pivot (max(users) name, max(smt) smt for rn in (1 u1, 2 u2, 3 u3)))
select null schema_, null table_, u1_name u1, u2_name u2, u3_name u3 
  from t where rownum = 1 union all
select schema_, table_, to_char(u1_smt), to_char(u2_smt), to_char(u3_smt) 
  from t
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1cd168af6ea5b6d2e4bed0a1f636171b)</sup>**

If you really need to put user names in headers then you have to use dynamic SQL or external code-writing-code technique.

I don't know if you really have columns like `table` or `schema`, these are reserved words, also once you write `tran_count` and in title `count_date`, so I am somewhat confused. But you can see in the linked dbfiddle working example with columns `schema_, table_, users, tran_count`.

Comment: select schema_, table_, to_char(u1_smt), to_char(u2_smt), to_char(u3_smt)   as you write like this but I have not only 3 this is just a demo, I have 1000 users. Also what's the use of dense_rank().

Comment: `dense_rank` is responsible for sorting, it's the main part of solution. If the number of users is dynamic you have to look at answers about `dynamic pivot`. As for now Oracle does not allow selecting in `in` clause, except `pivot xml`.